# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative DataKeys (Asp.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is (Asp.Net , C#)

```
    int index = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument);
    string str = GridView2.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();
    Session["studyuid2"] = str;
```

The Second Line Throws me the error **Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index**

and my gridview is

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" Height="100px" 
                    RowStyle-Height="25px" HeaderStyle-Height="30px" FooterStyle-Height="30px" 
                    CellPadding=5 CellSpacing=5  
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True" 
                    Width="100%" 
                    DataKeyNames="StudyUID" 
                    onrowcommand="GridView2_RowCommand" 
                    AllowSorting="True">
<RowStyle Height="25px"></RowStyle>
                    <Columns>
```

### -------------------------------

```
                    </Columns>

<FooterStyle Height="30px"></FooterStyle>

<HeaderStyle Height="30px"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: OK, so now you know that `index` is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the collection.  You should fix that.

Comment: Are you aware of how collections work? The index is `base-0`, meaning if there are 10 items, the first one will be `[0]` and the last one will be `[9]`. Make sure you're setting the `CommandArgument` to the correct value, and that `GridView2.DataKeys` actually has some values in it

Comment: in addition to the comments above, you could use a debugger and step through the code, looking why there is used an improper index

Comment: Personally I hate this exception.  It's silly the exception tells you the value is invalid for the range, but doesn't include the value or range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situations like this it's helpful to add more error handling.  It's unfortunate that the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` doesn't tell you the value of the argument and the valid range.  You can do it like this, and then it'll help you debug.

```
int index = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument);

try
{
    string str = GridView2.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();
    Session["studyuid2"] = str;
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex) 
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
        String.Format(
            "The index passed is not valid for the collection.  The index is '{0}' and must be between 0 and '{1}'.",
            index,
            GridView2.DataKeys.Count));
}
```

You could also do this by validating the index before calling `DataKeys[index]`, instead of relying on exception handling to catch and rethrow.

Comment: Now i Got this "The index passed is not valid for the collection.  The index is '0' and must be between 0 and '0'."                              "The index passed is not valid for the collection.  The index is '2' and must be between 0 and '0'." The Gridview doesnot sets the DataKeyNames properly

Comment: @user1612076, great, progress, right? So now you know the collection is empty.  Why is the collection empty?  Use the debugger now.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by calling DataBind() before trying to access the DataKeys[] collection.

Comment: @user1612076, great, thanks for posting a follow up comment with the root problem in case anyone else has the same issue and stumbles upon the question and answer.  Glad to help!